# concatenar em uma string números da array

Tags: javascript, array, concatenação-de-string

Preciso concatenar em uma única `string` todos os números da `array` - substituindo os números da matriz [1,2,5,6,11,13,15]

"números múltiplos de 2 substituir por `string`  "Yin"

"números múltiplos de 3 substituir por `string`  "Yang"

"números múltiplos de 2 e 3 substituir por `string`  "YinYang"

> preciso do retorno "1YinYangYin57Yin11Yang"  e  "Yang5YinYangYin"

no meu código não retorna como preciso!

tentei fazer nesse modo

```
function yinYang (array) {
 
  let concat = "Yin" + "Yang";
 
  for(let i = 1; i< 9; i++) {
 
  concat = concat + (i + "");
 
   }

 
   return(concat);
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a função [map][1]
e resto de divisão, poderia ser algo do tipo:

```js
function mapYinYang(values) {
  return values.map((item) => {
    if (item % 2 === 0 && item % 3 === 0) return "YinYang";
    if (item % 2 === 0) return "Yin";
    if (item % 3 === 0) return "Yang";
    return item;
  }).join("");
}

const values = [1, 2, 5, 6, 11, 13, 15];

console.log(mapYinYang(values));
```

```
  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
```

Answer (score -1):

Para verificar se um número é múltiplo de outro usa-se o resto da divisão. Podemos criar um array com o resultado e depois usar o join() para concatenar todos os elementos do array.

```
var array = [1,2,5,6,11,13,15]

function yinYang (array) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[i] % 3 == 0) {
            result.push("YinYang");
        }
        else if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            result.push("Yin");
        }
        else if (array[i] % 3 == 0) {
            result.push("Yang");
        }
        else {
            result.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return result.join("");
}

console.log(yinYang(array));
```